# Изменяю текстовый файл в папке res андроид но после этого приложение не работает

Tags: android, java

5.Открываем Командную строку (Обработчик команд Windows) в вышеупомянутой папке - думаю D:\Decompile (В папке по пустому месте при зажатой кнопке Shift нажимаем правую кнопку мыши и выбираем Обработчик команд Windows). Но почему-то командная строка не появляется, хоть делаю как написано.

Comment: @niknva, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Приведите код ошибки. Связано с тем, что вы используете неэкранированные символы.

Comment: Как это так изменили файл? Тупо открыли архив с инсталлом и вручную подправили что ли не пересобрав проект? Если да, то что тут удивляться, apk файл имеет определенную структуру, как и любой другой архив, но скорее всего не одинаковую с zip, поэтому внеся изменения вручную, вы скорее всего нарушили структуру файла.

Answer (score 1):

Нельзя редактировать собранные и скомпилированные APK файлы c помощью обычного архиватора( ZIP ). Как минимум, при этом вы нарушаете целостность файла, а, следовательно, и контрольную сумму всего файла.

Необходимо либо пересобирать проект заново( компилируя при этом И ресурсы ), либо, если нет доступа к исходникам, декомпилировать APK и собирать заново. Процесс декомпиляции и пересборки APK довольно несложен, особенно, если в вашем случае, нужно подкорректировать лишь ресурсы.

Процесс декомпиляции и пересборки хорошо описан **[здесь](http://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=318729)**, например.